# Bouncycastle add comments in header

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg

In `gpg` you have the option to add comments to your signed file via the `--comments` option. Is there anything available for this on BouncyCastle icw Java ?

For example in `gpg` :

```
gpg 
--batch              ^     
--digest-algo SHA256 ^     
--comment "<PGPRequest>Something</PGPRequest>"
```

Comment: Did you read documentation? Is there anything that can help you? https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the output using the ArmoredOutputStream provided by bouncy castle:

```
    ArmoredOutputStream armoredOutputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(output);
    armoredOutputStream.setHeader("Comment", "<PGPRequest>Something</PGPRequest>");
```

Result:

```
    -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
    Version: BCPG v1.64
    Comment: <PGPRequest>Something</PGPRequest>
    (...)
```

There can only be one value for each header key, so you will have to extend ArmoredOutputStream to allow you to define multiple "Comment"

I hope that helps.